# Debug a single JUnit Method in a Play Framework (v2.5) App with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, playframework-2.5

We are developing a Java based Play Framework application.

I'm the only eclipse user in my team. My colleagues are using IntelliJ and they are able to run JUnit tests purely from within the IDE.

I wouldn't see this as a problem, since running the tests via `./activator` and attaching a remote debugger is no big deal, ***but***:

They can run one single @Test-annotated method of the whole test class and debug it. And I can't even find a way to run a single method using the `activator` command.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646307/running-a-single-junit-test-in-eclipse

Comment: Do you want to run a single Test method in Eclipse? Or particularly using activator?

Comment: I'm not able to start / run any code of the project from within eclipse. It would be nice to be able to do this, but if not possible I would be perfectly fine to just know a `./activator testOnly package.TestClass.testMethod()` call to run from the command line.