# Can I force Junit debugger to start debugging execution by a custom test case method using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, debugging, junit, testcase

I have a Test Class containing 3 test methods like below example

```
public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        // logic of testing ADD
    }
    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        // logic of testing UPDATE
    }
    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        // logic of testing Delete
    }
}
```

I want to debug ONLY the second method `testUpdate()`
WITHOUT starting execution by any of other test cases `testAdd()`/`testDelete()`

When I put `breakpoints` in all test methods
I found that
**Order of Execution** not granted, and in some cases `testAdd()`/`testDelete()` methods runs before `testUpdate()`
Those cases waste a time because, I need to debug ONLY method2 = `testUpdate()`,
So why I should wait method1 or method3 to be executed however they are run quickly

To summarize
Can I force Junit debugger to start execution by a custom test case method using Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Dmytro comment.
The solution will be

1. In the `Package Explorer` or `Outline` view
2. Unfold the Test Class which contain test methods.
3. Right click on the required method you want to `Debug`
4. Select `Debug As` => `JUnit Test`

Comment: Yes this is in some way what I answered you

Comment: @KhalilM No dear, its a different, you mentioned that `selecting the method and click debug` but the right way to  `select method In the Package Explorer or Outline view` ... anyway Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use test execution order :

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order

other means :

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)
```

by choosing for example to use NAME_ASCENDING you should change the second test name to make it alphabetically came before the other tests

Comment: Its good, but in most cases, We don not matter about unit testing methods order

Answer (score 1):

have you tried selecting the method and click debug? or have you tried executing whole tests and later select your method right click and debugg?

Comment: Yes, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

**Preferred way**: any modern IDE has an ability to run and debug a specific test. Refer a manual of your IDE.

**Dirty way**: ignore the rest test cases except one:

```
public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testAdd() {
        // logic of testing ADD
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        // logic of testing UPDATE
    }

    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testDelete() {
        // logic of testing Delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!, please can you show how we can do that using `Eclipse` IDE?

Comment: I don't use `Eclipse` but seems answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646307/running-a-single-junit-test-in-eclipse may help you.